# A group of 10+ Windows 7 machines randomly unable to resolve domain names

Tags: windows-7, networking, dns

Over the past month a group of Windows 7 machines have randomly lost the ability to resolve a domain name. Pinging the DNS address works just fine. It seems to be one or two machines at a time which are behind the same gateway. Restarting the computer works for a temporary fix (sometimes a day sometimes a few weeks). The only other fix that seems to work is to change the gateway to #2 then back to #1 and the computer will again resolve domain names without the reboot. 
The issue has stumped me and I have replaced a few NIC cards hoping it is a driver issue as the current NIC is part of the motherboard which is getting pretty old.
Has anyone experienced an issue like this? Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe a flaky router or switch?

Answer (score 0):

Are these Windows 7 machines using DHCP or have static IP addresses?

There might be some machine/router on the network erroneously offering DHCP leases, which incorrectly set the DNS to an IP which isn't a DNS server.

The next time a machine loses its ability to resolve domain names, run `ipconfig /all` and double check the DNS Server.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The machines all have static IP addresses. All route to the same gateway and DNS servers are set at the machine itself. When I run ipconfig /all I am able to see that the DNS server itself has not changed and when I ping the DNS IP I am successful. Resolving domain names seems to be what is lost as the DNS server is still accessible from the computer and the network configuration has not changed. Thank you for the response please let me know if you have any other ideas.

Comment: @sneakernetsec If the DNS server you are using is still responding to pings, I guess this means that the network is not really the issue (at least not between the DNS server and the Windows 7 machines). Would it be acceptable for the Windows 7 machines to use alternative DNS servers? E.g. google public DNS (8.8.8.8) or OpenDNS (208.67.222.222). Try setting the Windows 7 machines to query these instead, and see if the problem disappears. If this resolves the problem, it is most likely that the DNS daemon has stopped answering queries (hung).

Comment: Today 10 computers needed restarted in one hour. I wasnt in the office but a simple restart fixes the issues temporarily. Some use different DNS servers now because we tried switching to OpenDns, our ISP and Google. I'm lost, nothing looks wrong in ipconfig or elsewhere on the network.